# List of daily quests

Tags: paragon

What are the quests in Paragon, and how often can you complete them?

Comment: Asking for things that will happen in the future is off-topic for Arqade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wiki:](http://paragon.wikia.com/wiki/Daily_Quest)

Three quests are renewed daily. The possible quests are:

- Hero Defeater - Secure 5 Kills or Assists against enemy heroes.
- Hero Conqueror - Secure 10 Kills or Assists against enemy heroes.
- Hero Eliminator - Secure 15 Kills or Assists against enemy heroes.
- Hero Bruiser - Inflict 10,000 damage to enemy heroes.
- Hero Wrecker - Inflict 15,000 damage to enemy heroes.
- Hero Demolisher - Inflict 20,000 damage to enemy heroes.
- Match Win - Win 1 match.
- Melee Win - Win 1 match as a melee hero.
- Inhibitor Defeater - Destroy 1 inhibitor.
- Inhibitor Conqueror - Destroy 2 inhibitors.
- Inhibitor Eliminator - Destroy 3 inhibitors.
- Tower Defeater - Destroy 1 tower.
- Tower Conqueror - Destroy 2 towers.
- Tower Eliminator - Destroy 3 towers.
- Structure Conqueror - Inflict 500 damage to enemy structures.
- Minion Defeater - Kill 50 enemy minions.
- Minion Conqueror - Kill 100 enemy minions.
- Minion Eliminator - Kill 250 enemy minions.

Comment: Isn't there a Ranged Win? (1 win w/ Ranged Hero)